# Get the whole received bytes by a single call of "recv()" function call of WinSock2 Api

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, winsock, winsock2

I wrote a client app in android device using bluetooth android api and server app in windows pc using winSock2 api. Now my problem is recv() can not receive more than 1011 bytes in a single call.
Here is the code of send and receive method-

Android data sending code is like as:

```
byte[] testByte = new byte[1024];
outputStream.write(testByte );
```

Windows Receiving code is

```
char response[4096];
//acceptedSocket: client socket accepted by server
//protocol- BTHPROTO_RFCOMM
//SocketType - SOCK_STREAM;
receivedBytes = recv(acceptedSocket, response, sizeof(response), 0);
```

here receiveBytes = 1011. So i have to call recv() again to receive next 13 bytes.

Now if i change the `recv()` function call with flags **MSG_WAITALL** and response array to be of size 1024, then it returns **receivedBytes = 1024** bytes, I can receive whole 1024 bytes at a single call.

> In that case, i have to send size of the data first from the
>   client app and then have to send the data. So I need to transmit two times
>   from Android client app.

But I want to receive whole 1024 bytes at a single call of `recv()` and transmitting once from Android client PP;

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `recv()` rather than `rece()`? Anyway, call it in a loop until it returns 0.

Comment: Why did you mis-spell `recv()` eight times in a row? Do you program like this?

Comment: @EJP sorry for that. not accustomed with windows API  function naming. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it's recv(). Sorry for that. isn't recv() a blocking call ? it returns 0 when the connection has been gracefully closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`recv()` isn't specified to transfer more than one byte at a time.

You have to loop.

Comment: but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx) says For connection-oriented sockets (type SOCK_STREAM for example), calling recv will return as much data as is currently available—up to the size of the buffer specified

Comment: @MohiuddinSohel: yes, but the data arrives in packets.  As soon as the first packet arrives, recv() returns all the data it contains, without waiting for the next one.  (I'm slightly puzzled as to why you would be receiving 1011 bytes in particular, but I'm sure there's a reason.)

Comment: @MohiuddinSohel *'Up to* the size of the buffer size specified.' In other words, possibly less.